# What "-e $ar", "3<&0 ", "0<$Arq", "exec 0<&3" do? I've seached and dont find a proper an

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I searched and could not find an answer to remedy my doubts.

```
 1. if [ -e $arq ]; 
 2. exec 3<&0 
 3. exec 0<$Arq
 4. exec 0<&3
```

Can someone help me understand what these lines mean?

Comment: Sorry, but your _I searched_ is an empty bla-bla. Googling for `shell if "-e"` and/or `shell exec 3` - both returns relevant results.

Answer (score 0):

1. TRUE if ${arq} exists
2. Link file descriptor #3 with stdin
3. stdin replaced by file ${arq}
4. restore stdin from file descriptor #3